# Restrict multiple php script instances

Tags: php, validation, multiple-instances

I have a script that is running multiple times cause the validation is taking longer and allowing multiple instance of the script. It is supposed to run about once a day but yesterday `script_start()` ran 18 times all right around the same time.

```
add_action('init', 'time_validator');

function time_validator() {
    $last = get_option( 'last_update' );        
    $interval = get_option( 'interval' );
    $slop = get_option( 'interval_slop' );

    if ( ( time() - $last ) > ( $interval + rand( 0, $slop ) ) ) {
        update_option( 'last_update', time() );
        script_start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds messy, that you've detected 18 instances of your script running although you don't want that. You should fix the code which calls those script instances.

However, you can implement this check into the script itself. To make sure that the script runs only once you should use [`flock()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php). I' ll give an example:

Add this to the *top* of your code that should run only once a time:

```
// open the lock file
$fd = fopen('lock.file', 'w+');

// try to obtain an exclusive lock. If another instance is currently 
// obtaining the lock we'll just exit. (LOCK_NB makes flock not blocking)
if(!flock($fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    die('process is already running');
}
```

... and this and the end of the critical code:

```
// release the lock
flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
// close the file
fclose($fd);
```

The method described is safe against race conditions, it really makes sure that a critical section runs only once.